# Excel VBA SVN Client / Integration

Tags: svn, excel, version-control, vba, diff

Can anyone recommend an SVN client for use in Excel with VBA (code modules only).  Ideally, I would also like SVN to ignore case when diffing prior to committing changes so as to avoid excessive churn in the repository (VBA has an annoying habit of changing the case of variables all over the project).

Comment: I've put together a COM Add-In for Excel that places a toolbar in the VBA editor that integrates with TSVN via it's shell commands.  I'd be happy to send it to you as is.  The code is all c# and vb.net.  You can ask me any questions you'd like, email is in "website"

Comment: Cheers - I have dropped you a mail Jason

Currently we are using ToirtoiseSVN and Beyond Compare but it means we have to first export the components which is a slight pain.  I just wondered if others had a more elegant solution.

Comment: If you chose not to export your components, my VbaDiff tool can make diff'ing revisions much easier. It integrates well with TortoiseSVN. You'll find the link on my profile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) integrates well with the Windows File Explorer and allows for the integration of an external diff tool (like [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/).

[Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) has a specific plugin for Visual Basic code that appears to ignore case for 'unimportant text', meaning anything *not* in quotes.

I don't think this will solve the SVN churn issue, however.  I don't believe that SVN uses the external diff program to decide whether a file has changed prior to committing, and I don't know of any way to override this behavior.

Comment: One workaround I found was to setup a workspace in Beyond Compare that compared the .svn\text-base folder to the working copy folder. That allowed me do a quick diff with rules so that I could revert case-only changes before examining the other diffs prior to commit.

Comment: TortoiseSVN is for the file explorer, the question was about VBA in Excel

Answer (score 9):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/SourceTools.aspx
might do what you want

Comment: I wonder why this wasn't upvoted although it's the only accurate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the following applications.

http://officesvn.codeplex.com/

http://code.google.com/p/msofficesvn/

Comment: Neither of those have special support for VBA, do they?

Answer (score 2):

Wow, my search for Excel VBA SVN led me to a 9 year old thread.  So I guess I'll update.

The msofficesvn above (moved to sourceforge/github) is the best svn option I have found but hasn't been updated in 2 years and it only manages entire documents.  The OP and myself are looking for control of individual bas files.

I recently started using [Rubberduck](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck) which is an Excel VBA git interface that manages the tricky export/import to/from your git repo.  It is currently supported and, while a bit tricky, works.

My org not only forces the use of Windows it is kinda resistant to git and is lingering with SVN, but I don't think there is an Excel VBA SVN tool so will quietly stick with Rubberduck.  I hope this helps someone else.

UPDATE:
As I've spent more time on Excel VBA I've realized you don't absolutely need Rubberduck.  You can get by with just git for Windows.  You will, however, need to carefully manage the export/remove/import yourself.  This may be preferable as I have found that if you do anything with Rubberduck outside of very basic add and commit functions, very unhappy things happen to your modules.  Trying to check out a new branch sends you back to your initial commit and overwrites all your modules.  Close Excel first, do your git operations, then reopen Excel and reopen your repo in Rubberduck.

If you do want to manage yourself but want menus and forms, there is [TortiseGIT](https://tortoisegit.org/) and [TortiseSVN](https://tortoisesvn.net/) which integrate into Windows Explorer.